# D: Overriding opDispatch in subclass

Tags: inheritance, d, overriding, opdispatch

Is there any way to override opDispatch in a subclass?
What I actually want to do is to pass around a variable with the superclass as its static type, but which redirects calls to opDispatch to its sub-type (the dynamic type).

Basically, I want this code to print "Sub" instead of "Super".

```
import std.stdio;

class Super
{
     void opDispatch(string m)()
     {
         writeln("Super");
     }
}

class Sub : Super
{
    override void opDispatch(string m)()
    {
        writeln("Sub");
    }
}

void main()
{   
    Super s = new Sub();
    s.callingOpDispatch; // Writes "Super" instead of "Sub"
}
```

I'm dumbfounded, as I cannot force the compiler to look for method overrides by using abstract methods (D doesn't allow abstract templated methods).

PS: Could someone please create the tag opDispatch? (It seems to me that it would be good for D?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Member template functions cannot be virtual and hence cannot be overridden.

http://dlang.org/function.html#virtual-functions

opDispatch is templated function. These two calls are identical:

```
s.callingOpDispatch();
s.opDispatch!("callingOpDispatch")()
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Michal said, templates cannot be virtual, so what you want to do is have the template forward to another function:

```
    import std.stdio;

    class Super
    {
            public final void opDispatch(string m)()
            {
                    opDispatchImpl(m);
            }

            protected void opDispatchImpl(string m) {
                    writeln("Super");
            }
    }

    class Sub : Super
    {
            protected override void opDispatchImpl(string m)
            {
                    writeln("Sub");
            }
    }

    void main()
    {
            Super s = new Sub();
            s.callingOpDispatch; // Writes "Sub" now
    }
```

Note that the impl isn't a template, it is now passing name as a regular runtime parameter, so beware of that if performance is important.

But then you can override the opDispatchImpl in subclasses and make it work.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately performance is a prime concern (Edited OP to communicate this).

Comment: eh, this isn't runtime evaluation, the code is still compiled, but the string is runtime here. Another option would be to do a static if in opDispatch to send certain strings to different virtual methods. Though at that point, you might as well just write a regular interface without opDispatch at all....

Comment: You are right, of course. In my specific instance of the original problem, the only way (known to me as of this writing) to ensure acceptable performance is to use the compile time string argument to mix in code. I was in a hurry to continue working on the problem, so I regrettably decided to start talking out of my ass. I'm sorry.